# Plugin 'flutter' is incompatible with this installation Android Studio 3.6.3

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, intellij-plugin

I am trying to install flutter and dart into Android studio and for [reasons beyond my comprehension](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008086019-Android-Studio-Plugins-marketplace-not-working) i cannot use the plugins marketplace online so i have to download the plugins manually by the browser from [the marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/androidstudio) and add the plugins from disk.

So I've downloaded both flutter and dart zip files versions as following

[Dart: 201.6668.156](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart/update/83642)

[Flutter: 45.1.3](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/update/83331)

when try to "Install Plugin from disk..." an error message appears stating
"Plugin 'flutter' is incompatible with this installation"
same issue occurs when installing dart plugin

if they're not compatible then which dart/flutter versions are compatible with the latest android studio version?

This is my Android Studio About

> Android Studio 3.6.3 Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6392135, built on April
>   14, 2020 Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 amd64 VM: OpenJDK
>   64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Windows 10 10.0 GC: ParNew,
>   ConcurrentMarkSweep Memory: 1237M Cores: 8 Registry:
>   documentation.show.toolbar=true, ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true,
>   debugger.watches.in.variables=false Non-Bundled Plugins:
>   com.jetbrains.ChooseRuntime, pl.charmas.parcelablegenerator

Comment: My Config: Android Studio 3.6.3 (Same build), Flutter Plugin: 45.1.1, Dart Plugin: 192.7761

Comment: You can install/update the packages from Android Studio. Go to Plugins > Marketplace and install Flutter. It will install dart as well.

Comment: @MidhunMP I've tried your config and it did install properly, but now when creating a new flutter project and running it, i get a bunch of [Fatal Error] and a list of error lines starting with the following line  
"Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'."

i am not sure if it's related to having an outdated flutter/dart plugin or not but flutter doctor sees no issues

Comment: @Xihuny as i stated in the question "for reasons beyond my comprehension", i cannot use the Marketplace in android studio to search for plugins, I've had created a question regarding this issue in the IntelliJ fourms 

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008086019-Android-Studio-Plugins-marketplace-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who comes through a similar issue, here's how i fixed it for myself.

First, thanks to @Midhun MP's comment on the main question, i used his config by manually downloading and installing them.

> android Studio 3.6.3 (Same build),  [Flutter Plugin: 45.1.1](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/versions/stable/83329), [Dart Plugin: 192.7761](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart/versions/stable/72602)

This installed flutter and dart correctly, but then another issue showed up.

When i attempt to run a newly created flutter project i get a bunch of [FATAL ERROR] messages.

The solution for the second issue can be found in [this github issue comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39729#issuecomment-587651515)

Basically write the following commands on the terminal in your project's directory

- clean gradle cache
- run 'flutter precache'

Those were enough to fix my [FATAL ERROR] issues, but if the issues persist then you can [try the following solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39729#issuecomment-587667967)

> change the url at MAVEN_REPO in the flutter.gradle file (located in directory flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/) from http://download.flutter.io to https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io

Answer (score 12):

Go to plugin settings and
Update the Flutter and Dart plugins

File --> Settings --> Plugins --> Installed

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If the update option is not available for the individual plugins as mentioned in zk_regen's answer, from the menu: File > Settings ... (Settings dialog appears) ... Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Updates, then use the Check Now button against the Automatically check for plugin updates. Most likely, newer updates of your desired plugins would be available there.

Comment: this isn't a plugin update issue, this is a plugin installation issue, the plugins refused to be installed to begin (which is the issue stated in the question)

Answer (score 7):

Restart Android Studio. After that in File -> Preferences -> Plugins, it shows an 'update' button next to Dart to update the plugin.

Comment: i couldn't install the dart plugin to begin with, this is stated in the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. This is what I did:

1. Remove Android Studio
2. Reinstall latest version of Android Studio
3. Open Android Studio, go to preference --> plugins --> marketplace then reinstall all the plugins, including Dart and Flutter. I don't know if this has any significance but I installed Dart first then Flutter.

Then it works

Hope this helps.

Comment: haven't tried this solution but tried another which i wrote an answer for

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and my class code was not showing keywords and was looking like plain text.

**What i did is:**
I just went to android studio option on top left of the screen and clicked checked for updates. Android studio version was updated and after restart it started working!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Came here to add that the error message similar to this:  `Plugin 'Flutter' (version '6X.X.X') is not compatible with the current version of the IDE, because it requires build 221.4906.8 or newer but the current build is AI-211.7628.21` doesn't come up if you just choose Update plugin. So every time you update the plugin (not manually) it will download and "update" but when you check back it's still in its past version with the option Update again. This error appears if you choose Update from disk (manual update)

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that your internet connection is stable. After restarting the WiFi issue was resolved.